# JSON or XML or serialized array to save in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json

Web app. Get data from services in **json & xml** formats. And from internal module in hash.

Decided to choose one format for all stored data.

details :

1. More read than write.
2. Data low nested (< 10).
3. Char count between 1000 - 100000.
4. Programming language - ruby.
5. Framework rails.
6. DB mysql.

What's your recommendation?

Comment: Rails version = 2.2 (requirement)

Comment: Marshal is great. Faster than everything else. 
Reccomend for data storage.
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons, we store large hashes as **serialized Ruby objects in Marshal format**. You need a column type of Blob. This works really well. JSON would be fine but we found it a little slower to marshal / un-marshal. I'd stay away from XML unless you really need interoperability with a third party/

Comment: thanks. will try Marshal now. Already decided to run away from xml.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to make the column a mediumblob. You can then just do Marshal.dump / Marshal.load into / from the column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm storing it as JSON in MySQL for a similar project since it offers a lot of flexibility. XML would offer the same, but it's a little verbose and since my application is JavaScript based, JSON is helpful because the parsing step can be skipped.

You might also want to checkout [ActiveModel](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/) in Rails 3. It allows using a model which offers all the benefits you would get out of ActiveRecord but it doesn't need to be stored in a database. It is very useful for validations on your JSON/XML for example, even though ultimately it will be stored as a blob or large text.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend JSON over XML

For building or consuming API's, ActiveModel works well.

For straight JSON parsing YAJL-ruby is a nice library: 
http://rdoc.info/projects/brianmario/yajl-ruby

In Activerecord you can easily store hashes, arrays etc in text columns using by serializing the attr:

See "Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns" here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001799

Example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(:preferences => { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
```

Comment: I use serialize but have been bitten pretty hard by it in the past.  I would recommend using the Marshal/blob strategy.